# Trying to store values from file into array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm learning C and trying to write a program to hold music information.
I'm reading from a file with the following contents:

```
Hello,Adele,2015
Sorry,Justin Bieber,2015
X Gon Give It To Ya,DMX,2002
```

And trying to do a fairly basic operation - look at each line until EOF, grab the content, tokenize using `','` as delimiter, store each part of the string into 3 variables, store those 3 variables into the global array using the global index, which is defined in main like this

```
Song SongList[1024];
int globalCounter;
globalCounter = 0;
```

The function I wrote looks like this, where `fp` is a successfully opened file, `SongList` is an array of `Song` structures and `globalCounter` is the global index of current position in array.

```
int getFileData(FILE *fp, Song *SongList, int globalCounter) {
    int newCount = globalCounter;
    char fileOut[1024];
    int lineno = 0;

    while (!feof(fp)) {
        if (fgets(fileOut, 1024, fp) != NULL) {
            newCount++;
            char *tokenizer;
            char *fileTitle;
            char *fileArtist;
            char *fileYear;

            tokenizer = strtok(fileOut, ",");
            int counter = 0;
            fileTitle = tokenizer;
            counter++;
            while (tokenizer != NULL) {
                tokenizer = strtok(NULL, ",");
                if (counter == 1)
                    fileArtist = tokenizer;
                if (counter == 2)
                    fileYear = tokenizer;
                counter++; 
            }

            SongList[newCount].title = fileTitle;
            SongList[newCount].artist = fileArtist;
            SongList[newCount].year = fileYear;
            // prints the right values
            printf("%i\n", newCount);
            printf("TITLE: %s\n", SongList[newCount].title); 
            printf("ARTIST: %s\n", SongList[newCount].artist);
            printf("YEAR: %s\n", SongList[newCount].year);
        }
    }
    return newCount;
}
```

It looks like it works fine, however, when I try to do a simple print of contents before the return statement, I get garbage return data.

```
int counter = 0;
while (counter < newCount) {
    printf("%s, %s, %s", SongList[newCount].title, SongList[newCount].artist, SongList[newCount].year);
    counter++;
}
```

yields:

`X Gon Give It To Ya, DMX, 2002X Gon Give It To Ya, DMX, 2002X Gon Give It To Ya, DMX, 2002`

When I try to use pretty much the exact same while loop in another function, I get even more garbage data output.

```
(null), (null), (null), , ╨╦a, , DMXm
```

The song structure looks like this

```
typedef struct Song {
    char *title;
    char *artist;
    char *year; 
} Song;
```

I suspect the problem has a simple solution: something to do with type definitions of variables, missing */&, or not ending with '\0' - I'm not sure what is causing this though.

Comment: Every second question is about it... **allocate your strings!**

Comment: @EugeneSh. I originally allocated like this:    
char tokenPtr[40];
char fileTitle[40];
char fileArtist[40];
char fileYear[40];
but end up getting lots of errors like this
error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[40]' from type 'char [star]'
    tokenPtr = strtok(buffer, ",");
which means strtok output is incompatible with char [40] - leaving it as char[star] x worked but is causing what I talked about in the question

Comment: *Each* of your `Song` items has to have it's fields allocated. And to reduce the chance of being downvoted - remove justin Bieber from your list :)

Comment: In that printf statement, you're using `newcount` where I believe you should be using `counter` (otherwise you're just printing the same song several times).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `while (!feof(fp)) { if (fgets(fileOut, 1024, fp) != NULL) {` just use:

```
   while (fgets(fileOut, 1024, fp) != NULL) {
```

Note that your parsing with `strtok` is sloppy: the artist will start with a space, the year will start with a space and include the final line feed. Using a pointer and parsing by hand would be more precise.

You must store copies of the strings:

```
       SongList[newCount].title = strdup(fileTitle);
       SongList[newCount].artist = strdup(fileArtist);
       SongList[newCount].year = strdup(fileYear);
```

You may want to `free` these strings when you are done processing the data, unless you exit the program, in which case `free` is not necessary, but still recommended to help track potential memory leaks.

Also increment `newCount++;` **after** successfully storing the entry.

According to your description, you should also store `newCount` to the global variable `globalCounter`.

Your printing loop should use `counter` instead of `newCount`:

```
    int counter = 0;
    while (counter < newCount) {
        printf("%s, %s, %s\n",
               SongList[counter].title, 
               SongList[counter].artist, 
               SongList[counter].year);
        counter++;
    }
```

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Song {
    char *title;
    char *artist;
    char *year; 
} Song;

Song SongList[1024];
int globalCounter = 0;

int getFileData(FILE *fp, Song *SongList, int *globalCounter) {
    int newCount = *globalCounter;
    char fileOut[1024];

    while (newCount < 1024 && fgets(fileOut, 1024, fp) != NULL) {
        char *p = fileOut;
        char *fileTitle;
        char *fileArtist;
        char *fileYear;

        fileTitle = p;
        if ((p = strchr(p, ',')) == NULL)
            continue;
        *p++ = '\0';
        p += strspn(p, " \t");  /* skip blank characters */
        fileArtist = p;
        if ((p = strchr(p, ',')) == NULL)
            continue;
        *p++ = '\0';
        p += strspn(p, " \t");  /* skip blank characters */
        fileYear = p;
        p += strcspn(p, ",\n");  /* skip to ',' or '\n' or end of string */
        *p = '\0';

        SongList[newCount].title = strdup(fileTitle);
        SongList[newCount].artist = strdup(fileArtist);
        SongList[newCount].year = strdup(fileYear);

        // prints the right values
        printf("%i\n", newCount);
        printf("TITLE: %s\n", SongList[newCount].title); 
        printf("ARTIST: %s\n", SongList[newCount].artist);
        printf("YEAR: %s\n\n", SongList[newCount].year);
        newCount++;
    }
    return *globalCounter = newCount;
}

int main() {
    FILE *fin;

    if ((fin = fopen("test.txt", "r")) != NULL) {
        getFileData(fin, SongList, &globalCounter);
        fclose(fin);
    }
    for (int counter = 0; counter < globalCounter; counter++) {
        printf("%s, %s, %s\n",
            SongList[counter].title,
            SongList[counter].artist,
            SongList[counter].year);
        counter++;
    }
    return 0;     
}
```

Comment: Amazing answer!! Thank you :-) In using your code though, how do you get around this error? music.c:108:16: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
         if ((p = strchr(p, ',') == NULL))
                ^
music.c:113:16: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
         if ((p = strchr(p, ',') == NULL))

Comment: @unicornication: oops! my bad, there were 2 typos, I fixed the answer.  btw, I did not compile the code, sorry for any other errors.

Comment: It runs fine! The only issue is two missing parenthesis after the NULL) 's, I made an attempt to edit your answer, but 6 edit character limit. Thank you very much!

Comment: @unicornication: I edited the answer already, `if ((p = strchr(p, ',')) == NULL)` should be fine, no missing parentheses anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You need to duplicate the string.   You do not just keep a pointer to the strtok return.  (And you should check the return value of strtok and strdup for errors and deallocate the memory when done with a Song record).
You are iterating the index too soon (skipping index 0).
And your testing of the return value is indexing the same last position in the for loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Song 
{
    char* title;
    char* artist;
    char* year; 
} Song;

Song SongList[1024];
int globalCounter = 0;


int getFileData(FILE* fp, Song* SongList, int globalCounter)
{
    int newCount = globalCounter;
        char fileOut[1024];
        int lineno = 0;
        while (!feof(fp))
        {
            if (fgets(fileOut,1024,fp) != NULL)
            {
                char *tokenizer;
                //char* fileTitle;
                //char* fileArtist;
                //char* fileYear;

                tokenizer = strtok(fileOut, ",");
                int counter = 0;
                SongList[newCount].title = strdup( tokenizer );
                //fileTitle = tokenizer;
                counter++;
                while(tokenizer != NULL)
                {
                    tokenizer = strtok(NULL, ",");
                    if(counter == 1)
                        SongList[newCount].artist = strdup( tokenizer );
                    //    fileArtist = tokenizer;
                    if(counter == 2)
                        SongList[newCount].year = strdup( tokenizer );
                    //    fileYear = tokenizer;
                    counter++; 
                }

                //SongList[newCount].title = fileTitle;
                //SongList[newCount].artist = fileArtist;
                //SongList[newCount].year = fileYear;
                // prints the right values
                printf("%i\n",newCount);
                printf("TITLE: %s\n", SongList[newCount].title); 
                printf("ARTIST: %s\n", SongList[newCount].artist);
                printf("YEAR: %s\n", SongList[newCount].year);
                newCount++;
            }
        }
    return newCount;
}

int main()
{
    FILE * fin = fopen( "test.txt", "rt" );
    int newCount = getFileData( fin, SongList, globalCounter );
    int counter = 0;
    while(counter < newCount){
        printf("%s, %s, %s",SongList[counter].title,SongList[counter].artist,SongList[counter].year);
        counter++;
    }

}
```

Test:

```
1212:/tmp$ g++ test.cpp  && ./a.out 
0
TITLE: Hello
ARTIST: Adele
YEAR: 2015

1
TITLE: Sorry
ARTIST: Justin Bieber
YEAR: 2015

2
TITLE: X Gon Give It To Ya
ARTIST: DMX
YEAR: 2002

Hello, Adele, 2015
Sorry, Justin Bieber, 2015
X Gon Give It To Ya, DMX, 2002
```

Comment: You forgot the ugly redundant end of file test: `while (!feof(fp))`

Comment: Missing `\n` in the last `printf`